# php trace post on website?

Tags: php

Hello guys is there anyway to trace post on another website ?
i want it for this
when users vote i give them points...
for example this site

http://srstats.com/server/vote/termination

When they vote successfuly they will got the points
I think if there no captcha curl could do it...
Is that possible ?

if its yes its will be cool to leave an example.
sorry for my bad english
thank you and thats all.

Comment: Please explain what you're doing more clearly. Which domain is being posted to/from? Which domain are you in control of?

Comment: i want to trace that website from my website if some one vote he will get points just this

Comment: you cant use ajax because there privacy its only works at site with same domain

Answer (score 0):

You can't take other website's POST data and use it in a script, no.

However, many vote sites do offer some kind of validation system that you can use to ensure a user who visited the site did actually vote.

If the above isn't available, you could have a link to the site from your own site, and give points whenever it is clicked. Obviously this is easily exploitable by clicking and not voting, but if you impress the importance of voting upon the users you might be able to get a fairly decent rate of clicks->votes.

Comment: i know i can do this but you cant know if they closed the vote